# Script16389: unspecified error

Tags: javascript, .net, telerik

I got "script16389: unspecified error" error in IE9 when I tried to open a RadWindow on popup.

```
...
var oWnd = $find(<% myRadWindow.ClientID %>);
oWnd.show();
...
```

I tried to debug and it's dead after run `oWnd.show()`

Comment: Yeah, a nasty IE iframe bug. Read this for more options: [http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/aspnet-ajax/window/details/opening-a-modal-radwindow-on-page-load-inside-radwindow-under-ie9-and-ie10](http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/aspnet-ajax/window/details/opening-a-modal-radwindow-on-page-load-inside-radwindow-under-ie9-and-ie10). Upgrading is the one I advise ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try to push `document.documentElement.focus();` before `oWnd.show()`. Maybe when you show the RadWindow, there's no activate or focused element.